# Whenever I am trying to deploy my react app on gh-pages this error is coming?

Tags: reactjs

Whenever I am trying to deploy my react app on gh-pages this error is coming

Cloning into 'C:\Users\Yasin\Desktop\HTML Projects\igvio-main\node_modules.cache\gh-pages\https!github.com!yasin-ai!igvio.git'...
error: unable to create file src/Media/4VGWsLNGhpXExFXdvAMxJ8Y7WxN-NoHaa0Jf01NNjWEZvR9IbI56c2-VrjIsmgZ0Cugensf-3qJDt3tkSRV-Y2LYGHrcPDJJmLPf9zpqFq94ocq16seQT0queKpLauUjwFKD2e7NZbs2jSDeJz0sx_1wr__psiwBSqkrW9kTiTPoe: Filename too long
fatal: unable to checkout working tree
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! instagram-tools@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the instagram-tools@0.1.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-17T14_07_49_625Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\Yasin\Desktop\HTML Projects\igvio-main> git config --system core.longpaths true
error: could not lock config file C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig: Permission denied
```

Comment: You shouldn't commit the node modules folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to long file names and doing a simple config as below resolved it

```
git config --system core.longpaths true
```

or another solution is try using this

```
git reset
```